# How to debug Smarty mail template codes, broken after upgrade

Tags: message-templates, smarty

I have a few Mail Templates that have conditional smarty codes like:

```
{capture assign=pp_scan}{contact.custom_74}{/capture}{if $pp_scan}You have already provided{else}You have not yet provided{/if} a scan of your passport.
```

This code ran just fine until I upgraded to 4.7.27 (from 4.7.21). Don't know if it is related to the upgrade or just a coincidence. Now, this code resolves to

> {capture assign=pp_scan}{/capture}{if $pp_scan}You have already provided{else}You have not yet provided{/if} a scan of your passport.

in the text of the email.

How do I debug the smarty code in mail templates? I tried adding {debug} to the mail template, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any chance in your settings file the "CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY" just needs to be turned back 'on'?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it. Thanks. Some follow-up, though. If this is a standard setting to have to reset after an upgrade, it would sure be nice to get a notice to this effect. Also, in Joomla, there is a civicrm.settings.php file under components/com_civicrm/ and under administrator/components/com_civicrm/ Changing the admin file fixed my problem. Presumably, the non-admin file affects situations where the smarty engine runs on the front-end, but I'm not sure what instances those would be. No real questions, here, just observations...

Comment: It's been a little bit since I've run an upgrade, but I think the Wiki makes mention of backing up your settings file as a part of the upgrade process.